# Referencing a linked table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having an issue with my databases. I have multiple access databases that share the same pool of users and passwords. They reference the table of users and passwords by a linked table to the 'master' database (the backend that holds the tables for users and passwords). I also have a table that stores the current users and the databases that they are logged into. The problem I'm encountering is that my logout method is not actually logging them out. This is what it is roughly:

```
    'this code is run on click of exit button

 Public Sub logout(UserName As String, database As String)

 On Error Resume Next

 Dim dbMine As DAO.database
 Set dbMine = CurrentDb

 Dim qr As String

   qr = "DELETE * FROM tblCurrentUsers WHERE username = '" & UserName & "' AND       Database        = '" & database & "' ;"
    'debug.print qr
   dbMine.Execute qr


  Application.Quit

 End Sub
```

The problem is, the records don't seem to be deleting. Do I need to set my database object to the source table instead of referencing the linked table that exists in the database on which the code is run? If so, do I just reference that database by relative path?

Comment: Does this query work as a saved update query?  Sometimes I find errors in my query when run it as a saved query

Comment: As HelloW indicated, do some experimentation and get the query working outside of code first. If it doesn't work there then your code isn't the problem.

Comment: It does work, and works in vba when it's run on the parent database that houses the actual currentUsers table. When it's run from databases that contain the LINKED currentUsers table, it does not appear to work.

Comment: As long as you use the name of the table as it appears in the database that you are calling your code from... it should work. Based upon the error you indicated in the comment on the answer, I'm thinking that there is no tblCurrentUsers and you should double-check the tablename.

Comment: Might be an idea to change the parameter name "database" to something else. It is a reserved word in Access. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dbFailOnError` option when executing query to catch the error details. See what error you get; that could help you in resolving of your issue.

```
Public Sub logout(UserName As String, database As String)
On Error GoTo mError:
Dim dbMine As DAO.database
Set dbMine = CurrentDb
Dim qr As String
   qr = "DELETE * FROM tblCurrentUsers WHERE username = '" & UserName & "' AND Database = '" & database & "' ;"
    'debug.print qr
   dbMine.Execute qr, dbFailOnError
  Application.Quit
Exit Sub
mError:
  MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't even realize I wasn't catching my errors. I deleted the resume next, and confirms my assumption. it is saying that it cannot find the referenced table. So, I guess I cannot reference a linked table and have to set the database = the parent database rather than the current one?

Comment: What happens when you type the following in the Immediate window? `?CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblCurrentUsers").Name` See, from Access's point of view there is no difference between linked and non-linked tables in a specific database - you can run `SELECT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` queries just as you would on a normal table. Might this table have a different name in the current database, even though it's called `tblCurrentUsers` in the source database?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Set dbMine = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
```

instead of

```
Set dbMine = CurrentDb
```

I've had similar issues when using CurrentDb.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237861(v=office.12).aspx,

> The CurrentDb method creates another instance of the current database, while the DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0) syntax refers to the open copy of the current database.

Perhaps there's some subtle difference in the way DAO or Access handles the "new instance of the current database".